# SMC2632W Wireless PCMCIA Card?

Tags: wireless, wubi, 7.10

I have an old Toshiba laptop with a SMC2632W Wireless PCMCIA Card. Unable to connect to a network under Ubuntu 7.10 (using Wubi as it cannot boot from a CD), however it works in Windows XP.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important things to check to ensure this card works:

1. Ensure the [linux-wlan-ng](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-wlan-ng) package is installed.
2. Ensure your card's firmware (internal software) is version 0.8 or higher. I had to use [this Windows utility](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0dcsogx0djn/Prism2-Firmware-update-to-0.8.3.zip) to update from 0.7.6 to 0.8.3 (This utility is Windows only, but needs to only be run only once per card. It should work for any Prism2 based card.)